# How to allow my CSS slide out element to push its neighboring content?

Tags: css, slider, push

I've made a slide-out element using CSS (in the footer, bottom left next to the picture) and would like for it to push the picture and the description to the right, when its hovered over and slid-out. I've made them all position:relative, am I missing something?

Quite new to trying to code, so hopefully the question makes sense.

Thanks!

Here's the link to the site: http://mirandascomplicated.tumblr.com/

Comment: It'll be much easier to get an answer if you post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `#slideout` element is not changing its width. It is fixed to 20px.

Additionally, the `#slideout_inner` `div` is being slid out by changing its left (correct?) position. This wont work because the left/right/top/bottom positioning of a relative element doesn't actually affect the space it *uses* (and therefore doesn't make the parent wider), it just affects where it is *displayed*. Try animating its left margin, padding or width instead.

Comment: Added the right amount of margin to #slideout:hover 
Thank you! Appreciate it.